# Print raw Postscript 3 Stream to printer incapable of PS3

Tags: printing, printer

I have a tool that sends a raw postscript 3 stream to a jetdirect socket (port 9100).
Currently i play around with running inetd to forward raw stream to lp and output to a CUPS printer queue.
Sadly it seems the cups-pdf crashes so still trying to find another solution.
Interestingly ps2pdf (from ghostscript) is working fine

I´m thinking of something like

inetd > ps2pdf > lp

Anybody done something like this before or any better idea?